# Boost serialization using separate .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, header-files

I am experimenting with the boost serialization library and I've gotten most of it working. The only problem is when i try to serialize an object that has separate .h and .cpp files. When i compile using this command:

```
g++ boostSerialize.cpp Class.cpp -lboost_serialization
```

i get this error:

```
/tmp/cc8kbW6J.o: In function `void boost::serialization::access::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive, Class>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, Class&, unsigned int)':
boostSerialize.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost13serialization6access9serializeINS_7archive13text_oarchiveE5ClassEEvRT_RT0_j[void boost::serialization::access::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive, Class>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, Class&, unsigned int)]+0x25): undefined reference to `void Class::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, unsigned int)'
```

this is what is in my .h:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Class{

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    int a,b,c;
    string stringy;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int);
    public:
        Class(int ab, int bb, int cb);

};
#endif
```

and my .cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"

using namespace std;

Class::Class(int ab, int bb, int cb){
    a = ab;
    b = bb;
    c = cb;
    stringy = "Text";
}

template<class Archive>
    void Class::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int){
        ar & a & b & c & stringy;
    }
```

I tried instead putting everything only into a .cpp and including that and it worked fine, so i know that it is something to do with the .h inclusion. For some reason it is not finding the serialize function? I guess i could just use a .cpp instead of both but i really like organization and i would like to use this for a big project.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is not with Boost.Serialization (as such), but that you are trying to separately compile a function template.

`Class::serialize` is a function template, which means that it gets instantiated on the basis of the types of the template parameters that get passed to is. When compiling `Class.cpp`, the compiler does not know what types `Class::serialize` will be instantiated with, and so it cannot generate the code.

Comment: So how do I tell the compiler what types it will be instantiated with? Or can i not?

Comment: @adamk33n3r: Good question! You can explicitly instansiate it in the .cpp file with `template void Class::serialize<boost::archive::text_oarchive>(boost::archive::text_oarchive &ar, const unsigned int);`.

Comment: Thanks so much! You are a brain meltdown saver! I've been trying to figure this one out for a while.

Comment: Better (?) solution: Move the implementation of your `serialize` method into the header.  This is the typical approach for ALL templates - their full implementation has to go in the header.